# Wordpress modifies content when importing post

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the PHP script below to import new posts into Wordpress.

```
require_once("wp-load.php");

$url = 'https://somejsonfeed.com'; // path to the JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$flights = json_decode($data, true); // decode the JSON feed

foreach ($flights['response'] as $item) {
$title = $item['flight']['iata_number']; 

if ( ! is_admin() ) {
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php' );
}

if ( get_page_by_title( $title, OBJECT, 'custom-post-name' ) == null ) {

// Insert post
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => '[jsoncontentimporterpro url=yes url=https://someapiwithakey123abc&iata_code=<cf_wpcf-arrival-airport\> value&type=something]',
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'custom-post-name'
);
// Insert post
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
// Insert post meta if available
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', 'meta_value' );

}
}else{
// Update meta value
update_post_meta($get_page->ID, 'my_key', 'meta_value');
}
```

But after importing the content it removes `<cf_wpcf-arrival-airport\>` and shows the content below in the Wordpress WYSIWYG editor.

```
[jsoncontentimporterpro url=yes url=https://someapiwithakey123abc&iata_code= value&type=something]
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: That's the content you're assigning in **'post_content' => "[jsoncontentimporterpro url=yes url=https://someapiwithakey123abc&iata_code=<cf_wpcf-arrival-airport\> value&type=something]"** and maybe the editor replaces **<cf_wpcf-arrival-airport\>** with an space or you'll see that by inspecting post's HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

No perfect solution, but a work around.

Used the https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-html-snippet/ plugin and imported the `post-content` value into a snippet. Then I used the snippet in the file above.